# How to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, wallpaper, android-drawable

I would like to set a certain `Drawable` as the device's wallpaper, but all wallpaper functions accept `Bitmap`s only. I cannot use `WallpaperManager` because I'm pre 2.1.

Also, my drawables are downloaded from the web and do not reside in `R.drawable`.

Comment: http://codingaffairs.blogspot.com/2016/06/how-to-convert-drawable-to-bitmap-in.html

Answer (score 224, accepted):

This converts a BitmapDrawable to a Bitmap.

```
Drawable d = ImagesArrayList.get(0);  
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
```

Comment: is this really the best way? Surely the drawable could be of another type and this would throw a runtimeException? For example it could be a ninePatchDrawble...?

Comment: @Dori you could wrap the code in a conditional statement to check if it is indeed a `BitmapDrawable` before casting it:


`if (d instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
   Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap(); }`

Comment: Can't believe the 64 upvotes? That code obviously only works if `d` already *is* a `BitmapDrawable`, in which case it's trivial to retrieve it as a bitmap... Will crash with `ClassCastException` in all other cases.

Comment: @Matthias not to mention that.. the question itself, same author, has 100 votes :/

Comment: This is so specialized to a trivial case.

Comment: For those who are complaining that this is wrong, have you guys checked the SO about page? It says that accepted answers do not necessarily mean the answer is correct, it means that the answer worked for the OP.

Comment: Too specialized.
This does *not* answer the OP's question "How to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap?" it answers "How can I convert a **BitmapDrawable** to a bitmap?"  Big difference.

Comment: @lemuel That does NOT mean we must refrain from pointing out the fact that the answer is WRONG.

Comment: I'm sorry if my comment offended you @RestInPeace

Comment: Surprise is: When a comment gets more up votes than answer itself.

Comment: After the introduction of `Adaptive` icons with Android Oreo, this started to cause lots of crashes with the apps that display other apps icons.

Comment: this gives ClassCastException

Comment: This is totally mistake. How do you confirm that an instance of a Drawable is an instance of BitmapDrawable? Furthermore, who told you that you can force cast an instance of a class to its subclass reference? Especially without a try/catch, you will have a exception in some cases.

Answer (score 1404):

This piece of code helps.

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                           R.drawable.icon_resource);
```

Here a version where the image gets downloaded.

```
String name = c.getString(str_url);
URL url_value = new URL(name);
ImageView profile = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.vdo_icon);
if (profile != null) {
    Bitmap mIcon1 =
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
    profile.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
}
```

Comment: where does str_url come from? I couldn't find any Drawable function related to strings... thanks for your help.

Comment: I think I found something: if "draw" is the drawable I want to convert to a bitmap then:  

Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)draw).getBitmap();

does the trick!

Comment: @Rob : if your Drawable is a BitmapDrawable only. (which means that your Drawable is but a wrapper around a Bitmap, actually)

Comment: This seems to scale the image from native resolution down to whatever resolution the device is set to.

Comment: note: this causes massive java.lang.OutOfMemoryError with JPG's

Comment: note: list stops scrolling smoothly while using this

Comment: This decodes a resource as a bitmap, it doesn't convert a 
Drawable into a bitmap but creates a bitmap from the source.

Comment: anything bigger than a small image will cause problems

Comment: This does not work with svgs. ```BitmapFactory.decodeResource()``` return null

Answer (score 834):

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
            return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        }
    }

    if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
    } else {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: This looks like the only answer that would work for any kind of drawable and also has a quick solution for a drawable that is already a BitmapDrawable. +1

Comment: Add @Mauro's solution to this after the check for BitmapDrawable and you've got a very ideal solution with any/ all quicker solutions Incorporated.

Comment: just one amendment: docs says about BitmapDrawable.getBitmap() that it may come back null. I say it may also come back already recycled.

Comment: Watch out: `getIntrinsicWidth()` and `getIntrinsicHieght()` will return -1 if drawable is a solid color.

Comment: So... another check for ColorDrawable, and we have a winner. Seriously, someone make this the accepted answer.

Comment: @kaay You can't really make another check for that, as you would still need width/height to create a canvas to draw the ColorDrawable, so you just need to make this method also take width and height as a parameter

Comment: @nbarraille In that case, you could just create a 1x1 pixel bitmap, and you're done. No extra parameters needed.

Comment: This doesn't work for all drawable types. For example GradientDrawable which i tried:

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

Comment: André you rocks dude! this help me with a RecyclerView that use a same ImageView with DrawableCompat tint.

Comment: `BitmapDrawable` fast path ignores possible tint, color filter, alpha.

Answer (score 159):

A `Drawable` can be drawn onto a `Canvas`, and a `Canvas` can be backed by a `Bitmap`:

*(Updated to handle a quick conversion for `BitmapDrawable`s and to ensure that the `Bitmap` created has a valid size)*

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    width = width > 0 ? width : 1;
    int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    height = height > 0 ? height : 1;

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: What happens if drawable param is null?

Comment: This method doesn't support VectorDrawable

Comment: Assuming you get a non-empty Drawable, why is there a need to check that width and height aren't 0?
Also, why do you need to use setBounds() if they're the same size?

Comment: Good solution ！Android 8.0 /sdk 26 ApplicationInfo.loadIcon(PackageManager pm) return a AdaptiveIconDrawable 。 Use your code can help me  cast AdaptiveIconDrawable to bitmap。

Comment: `BitmapDrawable` fast path ignores possible tint, color filter, alpha.

Answer (score 66):

**METHOD 1** : Either you can directly convert to bitmap like this

```
Bitmap myLogo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.my_drawable);
```

**METHOD 2** : You can even convert the resource into the drawable and from that you can get bitmap like this

```
Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo)).getBitmap();
```

For **API > 22**  `getDrawable` method moved to the `ResourcesCompat` class so for that you do something like this

```
Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.logo, null)).getBitmap();
```

Comment: ResourcesCompat only works if the drawable is a BitmapDrawable, if you are using VectorDrawable, then you are going to have a CCE.

Comment: Neither of these work with a *VectorDrawable* resource. The following error occurs - `android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable`

Comment: This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51742167/2253682) works well with Kotlin.

Answer (score 61):

android-ktx has `Drawable.toBitmap` method: https://android.github.io/android-ktx/core-ktx/androidx.graphics.drawable/android.graphics.drawable.-drawable/to-bitmap.html

From Kotlin

```
val bitmap = myDrawable.toBitmap()
```

Comment: This is the most simple solution for a `VectorDrawable` in Kotlin! Also shared [in this SO post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51742167/2253682) in more detail.

Comment: I am getting a blank Bitmap from this method.

Answer (score 51):

#### 1) Drawable to Bitmap :

```
Bitmap mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.icon);
// mImageView.setImageBitmap(mIcon);
```

#### 2) Bitmap to Drawable  :

```
Drawable mDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
// mImageView.setDrawable(mDrawable);
```

Comment: The question clearly states the drawable do not reside in R.drawable .. and your solution is for R.drawable.

Comment: R.drawable.icon is Int not Drawable

Answer (score 32):

very simple

```
Bitmap tempBMP = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image);
```

Comment: This is just plagiarism of the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3035869/984830) on this question three full years earlier

Answer (score 20):

The latest androidx core library (androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0) now has an [extension function: `Drawable.toBitmap(...)`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/android-room-release/core/ktx/src/main/java/androidx/core/graphics/drawable/Drawable.kt#42) to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap.

Comment: I can't quite figure out how to import that function. I assume that it works outside of Kotlin too?

Comment: From java, you need to import the Kt file containing the extension methods. Also, the signature is slightly more complex, as the receiver and the default parameters are not available in java. It will be like this: `DrawableKt.toBitmap(...);`

Comment: Make sure to include the parameters, since java doesn't see method overloads using default parameters
```kotlin
DrawableKt.toBitmap(
                mCornerTopLeftDrawable,
                mCornerTopLeftDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                mCornerTopLeftDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), 
                null
        )
```

Answer (score 19):

So after looking (and using) of the other answers, seems they all handling `ColorDrawable` and `PaintDrawable` badly. (Especially on lollipop) seemed that `Shader`s were tweaked so solid blocks of colors were not handled correctly.

I am using the following code now:

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    // We ask for the bounds if they have been set as they would be most
    // correct, then we check we are  > 0
    final int width = !drawable.getBounds().isEmpty() ?
            drawable.getBounds().width() : drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();

    final int height = !drawable.getBounds().isEmpty() ?
            drawable.getBounds().height() : drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

    // Now we check we are > 0
    final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width <= 0 ? 1 : width, height <= 0 ? 1 : height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Unlike the others, if you call `setBounds` on the `Drawable` before asking to turn it into a bitmap, it will draw the bitmap at the correct size!

Comment: Wouldn't setBounds ruin the previous bounds of the drawable? Isn't it better to store it and restore it afterwards?

Comment: @androiddeveloper, if the bounds have been set, we are just using those anyway. In some cases this is needed where no bounds have been set and has no intrinsic size (such as ColorDrawables in some cases). So width and height would be 0, we give the drawable 1x1 that way it actually draws something.
I could be argued we could do a type check for ColorDrawable in those cases, but this works for 99% of cases. (You can modify it for your needs).

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins What if it doesn't have bounds , and now it will get new ones? I'd also like to ask another question: what's the best way to set the bitmap size (even for BitmapDrawable) that gets returned ?

Comment: I suggest you carefully read the code. 
If the `Drawable` does not have bounds set it uses the `IntrinsicWidth/Height`. If they are both <= 0 we set the canvas to 1px.

You are correct if the `Drawable` does not have bounds it will be passed some (1x1 is most cases), but this is REQUIRED for things like `ColorDrawable` which DO NOT have intrinsic sizes. 
If we didn't do this, it would throw an `Exception`, you can't draw 0x0 to a canvas.

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins I mean that before calling this function, if the drawable doesn't have bounds, after calling it, it will have. Also, please answer the other question.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. Yes you are correct the original Drawable will now have bounds. I guess you would need to call `mutate()` to be really safe. This is used where you want a bitmap and throw away the drawable so its never been a concern.
As for Bitmap size? setting the Bounds defines how much actually gets drawn (as long as the Drawable plays nicely). But the Drawable can draw off the canvas (you just won't see it). The only true way to define the bitmap size would be to pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75021/discussion-between-chris-jenkins-and-android-developer).

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins What does mutate() do here? wouldn't it be easier to store the previous bounds, and set it again at the end? Can you please update the code to be more correct? Also, about the bitmap size, what you wrote is about the non-BitmapDrawable case. For BitmapDrawable, I guess you just use "createScaledBitmap" (or something similar, depends on how you want to scale) ?

Comment: `mutate()` would make a copy leaving the original drawable alone which would negate the issue of passing back in the original bounds.
I am seldom to change the code based on those points. If your use case requires it add another answer. I suggest you create another question for the Bitmap scaling.

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins: It should be noted that mutate() does not make a copy. It instead marks it as mutable so that it doesn't affect any other drawables sharing the same ConstantState. Additionally, bounds aren't contained within ConstantState, so mutate wouldn't work in this instance.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe this will help someone...

From PictureDrawable to Bitmap, use:

```
private Bitmap pictureDrawableToBitmap(PictureDrawable pictureDrawable){ 
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888); 
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp); 
    canvas.drawPicture(pictureDrawable.getPicture()); 
    return bmp; 
}
```

... implemented as such:

```
Bitmap bmp = pictureDrawableToBitmap((PictureDrawable) drawable);
```

Comment: As with Rob's answer, you're requiring a specific type of `Drawable`, in this case a `PictureDrawable`.

Comment: "Maybe this will help someone..."

Answer (score 13):

Here is the nice Kotlin version of the answer provided by @Chris.Jenkins here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27543712/1016462

```
fun Drawable.toBitmap(): Bitmap {
  if (this is BitmapDrawable) {
    return bitmap
  }

  val width = if (bounds.isEmpty) intrinsicWidth else bounds.width()
  val height = if (bounds.isEmpty) intrinsicHeight else bounds.height()

  return Bitmap.createBitmap(width.nonZero(), height.nonZero(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888).also {
    val canvas = Canvas(it)
    setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    draw(canvas)
  }
}

private fun Int.nonZero() = if (this <= 0) 1 else this
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is better resolution

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}

public static InputStream bitmapToInputStream(Bitmap bitmap) {
    int size = bitmap.getHeight() * bitmap.getRowBytes();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.array());
}
```

Code from [How to read drawable bits as InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341770/how-to-read-drawable-bits-as-inputstream/6341899#6341899)

Answer (score 12):

> Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
> R.drawable.icon);

This will not work every time for example if your drawable is layer list drawable then it gives a null response, so as an alternative you need to draw your drawable into canvas then save as bitmap, please refer below a cup of code.

```
public void drawableToBitMap(Context context, int drawable, int widthPixels, int heightPixels) {
    try {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/", "drawable.png");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        Drawable drw = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), drawable, null);
        if (drw != null) {
            convertToBitmap(drw, widthPixels, heightPixels).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
        }
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Bitmap convertToBitmap(Drawable drawable, int widthPixels, int heightPixels) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(widthPixels, heightPixels, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, widthPixels, heightPixels);
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

above code save you're drawable as drawable.png in the download directory

Comment: Using BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher); gives "skia -- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'" in some devices, its better to use ContextCompat.getDrawable() and then to bitmap.

Answer (score 8):

Android provides a non straight foward solution: `BitmapDrawable`. To get the Bitmap , we'll have to provide the resource id `R.drawable.flower_pic` to the  a `BitmapDrawable` and then cast it to a `Bitmap`.

```
Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.flower_pic)).getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 6):

`BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` automatically scales the bitmap, so your bitmap may turn out fuzzy. To prevent scaling, do this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                             R.drawable.resource_name, options);
```

or

```
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.resource_name)
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this code.it will help you for achieving your goal.

```
 Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.profileimage);
    if (bmp!=null) {
        Bitmap bitmap_round=getRoundedShape(bmp);
        if (bitmap_round!=null) {
            profileimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap_round);
        }
    }

  public Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage) {
    int targetWidth = 100;
    int targetHeight = 100;
    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, 
            targetHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,
            ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,
            (Math.min(((float) targetWidth), 
                    ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
                    Path.Direction.CCW);

    canvas.clipPath(path);
    Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
    canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, 
            new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(),
                    sourceBitmap.getHeight()), 
                    new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));
    return targetBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In **Kotlin**, the easiest way is:

```
Drawable.toBitmap(width: Int, height: Int, config: Bitmap.Config?): Bitmap
```

like this:

```
val bitmapResult = yourDrawable.toBitmap(1,1,null)
```

where, just need a drawable variable, No resource, No context, No id

Comment: Your extension function causes a `Function 'toBitmap' without a body must be abstract`

Comment: @hannesach You need to use core-ktx dependency to get the extension

Answer (score 2):

ImageWorker Library can convert bitmap to drawable or base64 and vice versa.

```
val bitmap: Bitmap? = ImageWorker.convert().drawableToBitmap(sourceDrawable)
```

Implementation

In Project Level Gradle

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            ...
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }
    }
```

In Application Level Gradle

```
dependencies {
            implementation 'com.github.1AboveAll:ImageWorker:0.51'
    }
```

You can also store and retrieve bitmaps/drawables/base64 images from external.

Check here. https://github.com/1AboveAll/ImageWorker/edit/master/README.md

Answer (score 2):

if you are using kotlin the use below code. it'll work

// for using image path

```
val image = Drawable.createFromPath(path)
val bitmap = (image as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 // get image path from gallery
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultcode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultcode, intent);

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (intent != null && resultcode == RESULT_OK) {             
            Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();

            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

            //display image using BitmapFactory

            cursor.close(); bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath); 
            iv.setBackgroundResource(0);
            iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you read the question wrong. The question asks: how to get a bitmap from a drawable resource not system gallery

Answer (score 1):

I've used a few answers on this thread but some of them didn't work as expected (maybe they had worked in older versions) but I wanted to share mine after a few tries and errors, using an extension function:

```
val markerOption = MarkerOptions().apply {
    position(LatLng(driver.lat, driver.lng))
    icon(R.drawabel.your_drawable.toBitmapDescriptor(context))
    snippet(driver.driverId.toString())
}
mMap.addMarker(markerOption)
```

This is the extension function:

```
fun Int.toBitmapDescriptor(context: Context): BitmapDescriptor {
    val vectorDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.resources, this, context.theme)
    val bitmap = vectorDrawable?.toBitmap(
        vectorDrawable.intrinsicWidth,
        vectorDrawable.intrinsicHeight,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap!!)
}
```