# android animated-rotate won't rotate ccw

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to get a custom indeterminate `ProgressBar` by using a rotating drawable in Android 4.1. I'm doing this as following:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="360"
android:toDegrees="0"
android:drawable="@drawable/image_for_rotation"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%" />
```

it seems like `fromDegrees` and `toDegrees` parameters just don't work, the image only rotates clockwise, but I need in to rotate ccw. When I change `animated-rotate` to `rotate`, they start working, however this is not what I need. Any suggestion to get it working?

[image]

Comment: tried fromDegrees="0"
toDegrees="-360" ?
not tested dont know if works

Comment: yep. No effect, the image still rotates cw

Answer (score 4):

I think the point is if you use `<animated-rotate>` it is a non public API.

I can't find any official documentation about it.

and it is actually **ignoring** whatever values you put in `fromDegrees` and `toDegrees`. You can remove both attributes and it will still spin.

You said you don't want to use rotate, but that is the only other simple XML answer I can find:

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:drawable="@android:drawable/ic_lock_power_off"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="50%"
  android:fromDegrees="0"
  android:toDegrees="-360" />
```

What is the reason for wanting `<animated-rotate>` and not `<rotate>` ?

If you want to set a slower or faster frame count, you should check this answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14996762/413127

Comment: if it is not a public API, why does it work then? I use no external libs. Well its difficult to tell without seeing.. take a look at my ProgressBar. 'rotate' literally ROTATES it, nothing more. 'animated-rotate' runs smooth like a real frame-by-frame animation. That's why I'm looking for a way to customize it

Comment: As I said, read the stackoverflow post I linked you can control the frame rate.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
android:fromDegrees="360"
android:toDegrees="0"
```

to

```
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="360"
```