# how to rotate an image programmatically in a splashscreen instead of using progressbar?

Tags: android, rotation, functional-programming, splash-screen

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 30000;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            // close this activity
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}
```

Comment: Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html)

Comment: in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760381/rotating-image-animation-list-or-animated-rotate-android) there are some examples

Comment: Do you want to rotate it like a progress bar, infinious animation? Please provide some more info

Comment: @BojanKseneman > yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For image rotation use the following codes:

```
ImageView rotate_image =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash_Rotate);
    RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(30, 360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,  Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate.setDuration(2500);
    rotate_image.startAnimation(rotate);
```

Answer (score 1):

For API 11+ this should rotate an image around it's centre

```
yourView.setPivotX(yourView.getWidth() / 2);
yourView.setPivotY(yourView.getHeight() / 2);

float rotation = 360f;
yourView.setRotation(rotation);
```