# Android custom ProgressDialog Animation

Tags: android, progressdialog, customdialog

I am trying to make a custom animation progress dialog. I have a lot of use case as the code fetches a lot of data from the server via Async Task. So while waiting i want to show a custom spinner. For now, I am able to use a default progress dialog. The code goes like this:

```
pd = new ProgressDialog(getContext(),R.style.SpinnerTheme);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
        pd.show();
```

Now I want to make my own custom spinner which has a round icon in the center and a red color spinning spinner around the round icon.

Something like this: http://hpics.li/cd6acba

Tried to search a lot but didnt got any relevant answer. please help.

Answer (score 1):

So either you can have a image and rotate it or can have multiple images and change these one by one to get the effect. I prefer first one.
[Rotating image. Animation list or animated rotate? (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760381/rotating-image-animation-list-or-animated-rotate-android)

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know if I now understand you correctly.
But maybe check this out: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_loading_spinner.htm

[image]

Comment: Hey Peter. I want a continuous spinner, not percentage thing

Comment: @AdarshRaj: What do you mean by continuous spinner? Like the windows spinner when it is loading?

Comment: something like this: http://loading.io/loader/?use=eyJzaXplIjoxNSwic3BlZWQiOiIwLjgiLCJjYmsiOiJyZ2JhKDksNzYsMTM3LDApIiwiYzEiOiIjNTI4YmJmIiwiYzIiOiIyMCIsImMzIjoiOCIsInR5cGUiOiJyb2xsaW5nIn0=

Comment: with an image in the center

Comment: Yes. I think u didnt understand my question. The tutorialPoint's tutorial was had a progress dialog in the activity. I want a custom progress dialog which can be used from any point of the application. Therefore the tutorial was not useful

Comment: So I can't help you.