# Android: Changing Wallpaper to Drawable

Tags: java, android

I'm using this code to change the wallpaper of the android home

```
WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
wm.setBitmap(myBitmap);
```

I would like to set the background to a drawable. Is this possible?

Comment: Not really AFAIK. Even setResource() requires a JPEG/PNG resource. Your only option, I suppose, would be a live wallpaper.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: how to convert a Drawable to Bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/android-how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-bitmap)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll first have to convert the Drawable to a Bitmap. How to do this I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/android-how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-bitmap). You'll need to use the BitmapFactory class, specifically the decodeResource() method.

Simply pass in the Resources and the Resource ID as parameters, like so:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.my_drawable);
wm.setBitmap(bmp);
```