# android getting pictures from drawables

Tags: android

Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.phscale);

apart from above code any other ways to get the bitmap from drawables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to have full control over resource bits, you'd better put it either in `res/asset` or `res/raw` folders and then get access to them as:

```
InputStream is=this.getResources().getAssets().open("drawable.png");
//
is=this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myDrawable);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get your png name as string, you could use the following:

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("bug", "drawable",   "org.anddev.android.testproject");
```

[source](http://www.anddev.org/tinytut_-_get_resources_by_name__getidentifier_-t460.html)

Answer (score 0):

See th link
[How to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/android-how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-bitmap)