# How to read drawable bits as InputStream

Tags: android, imageview, inputstream

There's say some `ImageView` object. I want to read bits/raw data of this object as InputStream. How to do that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36062748/241986

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First get background image of the `ImageView` as an object of `Drawable`:

```
iv.getBackground();
```

Then convert `Drawable` image into `Bitmap` using

```
BitmapDrawable bitDw = ((BitmapDrawable) d);
Bitmap bitmap = bitDw.getBitmap();
```

Now use `ByteArrayOutputStream` to get the `Bitmap` into a `Stream` and get `bytearray[]`; then
convert the `bytearray` into a `ByteArrayInputStream`.

You can use the following code to get `InputStream` from `ImageView`.

### Full Source code

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashImageView);
Drawable d = iv.getBackground();
BitmapDrawable bitDw = ((BitmapDrawable) d);
Bitmap bitmap = bitDw.getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();
System.out.println("........length......" + imageInByte);
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: in this way recompress it!

Answer (score 6):

These methods below are useful because they work with any kind of Drawable (not only BitmapDrawable). If you want to use drawing cache as in David Caunt's suggestion, consider using `bitmapToInputStream` instead of `bitmap.compress`, because it should be faster.

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}

public static InputStream bitmapToInputStream(Bitmap bitmap) {
    int size = bitmap.getHeight() * bitmap.getRowBytes();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.array());
}
```

Comment: It does not re-compress the image, but why I must allocate bitmap pixels, it double the memory occupied!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the drawing cache to retrieve a Bitmap representation of any View class.

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = view.getDrawingCache();
```

Then you can write the bitmap to an OutputStream, for example:

```
b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, new FileOutputStream("/view.jpg"));
```

In your case I think you can use a [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) to get a byte[] from which you can create an InputStream. The code would be something like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(b.getByteCount());
b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, os);
byte[] bytes = os.toByteArray();
```

Comment: in the question Barmaley has mentioned that the question is meant for imageview

Comment: An ImageView displays an image. To capture any view's rendering, including ImageView, the above code will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for this:
[openRawResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29)

Comment: I didn't say about image stored in resource. I was talking about ImageView object inflated on screen (so the source is unknown)