# Setting device wallpaper to be a gradient background (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I have created a gradient drawable in the drawable folder. It is a shape in an xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient
                android:angle="45"
                android:centerColor="@color/centerColor"
                android:endColor="@color/endColor"
                android:startColor="@color/startColor" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I am trying to set the gradient as the wallpaper for the device using the app when a certain button is clicked. Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance. :)

Java Code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
//                WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager  = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.gradient);
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

                try {
//                    myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(+ R.drawable.gradient);
                    getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(b);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wallpaper updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

Comment: you will likely have to draw this gradient on the bitmap, save it, and only then - set the wallpaper. I don't believe you can set the XML drawable as a wallpaper

Comment: I tried converting the drawable to bitmap. The wallpaper did update but it only displayed the first color of the gradient... :)

Comment: then you likely did something wrong.

Comment: Probably I did. But, I can't seem to find the root of the problem... haha

Comment: your drawable has no size. You need to create a bitmap of some size, and draw the drawable on it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this even possible?

Yes, it is possible.

1. Include this permission in your `manifest`.

2. Create raw folder in your res folder and add that gradient inside the raw folder
3. And use this code in your application.

   ```
          WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager  = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
           try {
               myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.raw.your_gradient_drawable);
           } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
   ```

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32038517/5305430 with your raw file ?

Comment: Yup. I tried placing the gradient.xml in the "raw" folder to no avail. I do not have to use InputStream right? :)

Comment: I tried that too.  InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.gradient);

Comment: Sure. I have included the gradient and a snippet of the java code above. :)