# AndEngine Texture from Drawable

Tags: android, textures, andengine

I'm new to AndEngine.

For some reason, I have to create a TextureRegion from a Drawable variable.

I don't know if it is possible,

but my code is not working...

```
public class DrawableTextureSource implements ITextureSource {
    private final int mWidth;
    private final int mHeight;
    private final Drawable mDrawable;
    private final Context mContext;
    public DrawableTextureSource(Context context, Drawable D) {
        mContext = context;
        mDrawable = D;
        mWidth = D.getIntrinsicWidth();
        mHeight = D.getIntrinsicHeight();
    } // end DrawableTextureSource()
    public DrawableTextureSource(Context context, Drawable D, int W, int H) {
        mContext = context;
        mDrawable = D;
        mWidth = W;
        mHeight = H;
    } // end DrawableTextureSource()
    public int getWidth() {
        return mWidth;
    } // end getWidth()
        public int getHeight() {
        return mHeight;
    } // end getHeight()
        public Bitmap onLoadBitmap(Config pBitmapConfig) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1024, 1024, pBitmapConfig);
        mDrawable.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
        return bitmap;
    } // end onLoadBitmap()
    public DrawableTextureSource clone() {
        return new DrawableTextureSource(mContext, mDrawable, mWidth, mHeight);
    } // end clone()
} // end class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is not the best way of solving this problem, but you can turn your `Drawable` to a `Bitmap` and then create a `TextureRegion` from the `Bitmap`.
Here's the code for creating a `TextureRegion` from a `Bitmap`:

```
public class BitmapTextureSource implements ITextureSource {

        private Bitmap mBitmap = null;

        public BitmapTextureSource(Bitmap bitmap) {
            this.mBitmap = bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        public int getWidth() {
            return mBitmap.getWidth();
        }

        @Override
        public int getHeight() {
            return mBitmap.getHeight();
        }

        @Override
        public Bitmap onLoadBitmap() {
            return mBitmap.copy(mBitmap.getConfig(), false);
        }

        @Override
        public BitmapTextureSource clone() {
            return new BitmapTextureSource(mBitmap);
        }

    }
```

Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap) to help you make a `Bitmap` from your `Drawable`.

Hope you'll find a simpler way, but this should do the job as well. Good luck!

Comment: i want to arrange drawable-button in grid...i done with first part..show drawable on button..but do u have any idea how can fit in grid-rectangle...any suggestion?