# Modify pixels of texture in AndEngine

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine

I try to build game with destroyable world (similar to Worms). I want to have world as an texture and modify color and transparency  of some pixels around after explosion. I found way to build [texture from drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679925/andengine-texture-from-drawable) but I'm not sure that generating so much textures every time will not kill my device. Is there any way to access texture pixels more directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textures in openGL are not mutable. To update the texture, you have to redefine the TextureRegion. Take a look at the Update Textures example in Andengine Examples:
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/UpdateTextureExample.java

So i think you're already on the right path, and I hope that doesn't make your app unplayable. I bet you'll be fine.