# Accessing Android resource from external package

Tags: android, drawable

I would like to read a drawable image from an external package into a bitmap. For example, in package com.test.images I have an image called image1.png under the drawable-hdpi folder. I would like to read that image into a Bitmap object from another package, for example com.test.reader. Can someone give a solution?

I can use the getResourcesForApplication(packageName) to get access to the resources of the external package, but the resources object I get only has a getDrawable method; I want to get a Bitmap for the image.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get the Drawable object you'll have to convert it to a Bitmap Object.

[Refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap) to see one possible way to achieve this.

Comment: I have tried that but I get the error, 'BitmapDrawable cannot be resolved to a type'. This is strange.

Comment: Ok, I manually imported the android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable class (Eclipse wouldn't suggest it for me) and it compiles.

Comment: Weird. I wonder why auto import wouldn't find it. Good to know though.