# How to reduce the memory usage of background images?

Tags: android

In my app, I put PNG images into drawable directory and use them as activity backgrounds. Since the background image usually cover the whole screen, they are big and use a lot of memory. 
My background images are total opaque. Is there any way that I can optimize those background images, so they can take less memory? I heard that we can reduce the color-depth of the images so they take less memory when loaded, but I don't know how to reduce the color-depth? What tool can I use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [converting your drawable to a bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap)

and then using `BitmapFactory.Options` to reduce the sample size, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I find the use of [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) Library to be one of the best in providing various **configurations** for Image handling. And in those Configurations, we find the option to load the image in RGB_565 encoding which is capable of reducing memory consumption by upto 50% (have seen the results practically) and that is capable of making a huge impact on the memory consumption of your app.

> Use .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) in display options. Bitmaps in RGB_565 consume 2 times less memory than in ARGB_8888.