# Initializing Bitmap variable with bitmap drawable from resources is not working - using ANDROID

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-resources

I use the following code to initialize my bitmap variable:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)this.model.gameView.context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic1)).getBitmap();
```

When I try to log the width of that bitmap, the log does not even output anything for that call.

I know it's making it to that line, because I traced the code.

Also, when I try to do canvas.draw for the bitmap, nothing is drawn on the screen.

Everything I draw with rectangles works fine.

My picture resource is a PNG.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out.  It had nothing to do with the method of bitmap loading I used.
It was a logical error on my part. My code accidentally reached a case where my bitmap became null, and it tried to draw the null resource on the canvas.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this for your bitmap class.

```
public class DrawBitmap extends View
{
    Bitmap bitmap;

    public DrawBitmap(Context content)
    {
        super(content);

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pic1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);//whatever color you want, make sure it's not the same as your image
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, (canvas.getWidth()), 0, null);
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
public class Main extends Activity 
{

    DrawBitmap myView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myView = new DrawBitmap(this);
        setContentView(myView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using BitmapFactory.decodeResource
Have a look at the answer in this topic:
[How to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap)

Comment: Yes, I tried this at first, and just did it again, and it is behaving the same way.

Comment: Did you also try handling exceptions on that code? Maybe your png image is not in the right place in resource folder. I suggest check if it throws a Resource Not Found exception.