# Use Current Wallpaper as live wallpaper background

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas, live-wallpaper

I am getting the current wallpaper by using following code:

```
  final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
  final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
```

How can I create a bitmap from this?

like when I create a bitmap from res folder I use this

```
    Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
    b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.wall);
```

What code I should use to get current wallpaper into the bitmap so I can draw it on my canvas and use it as my live wallpaper background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Drawable` fetched should really be a [`BitmapDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html). You can verify this using `instanceof` if necessary.

That being the case, all you have to do is:

```
final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
final Bitmap wallpaperBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) wallpaperDrawable).getBitmap();
```

*EDIT*: If it turns out that the `Drawable` is NOT a `BitmapDrawable`, you can use the following method to convert it (found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10600736/1438733), credit to [André](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259237/andre)):

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```