# ANDROID Convert jpeg image stored in /res/drawable to Bitmap object

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap)

I have just started learning android, so im a newbie

I am trying to create an android application for image processing for my Project

I came accross the blog entry :

http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/image-processing-brightness-over-image/

I am facing the following problem;

I am unable to create a Bitmap object for my image stored as /res/drawable/pic_1.jpg

I have tried using

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/res/drawable/pic_1.jpg"); and called the function;

public static Bitmap doBrightness(myBitmap, int value) {.........}
```

but that didnt work;

then I tried,

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/res/drawable/pic_2.jpg");
imageview.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

without calling the `doBrightness()` function.yet,it displays nothing in the imageview.

so I guess `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` is returning null.

so what i wanted to know is,
how is it possible to create Bitmap object for an image stored in /res/drawable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9390776/1289716

Answer (score 4):

you should get the Image via the resources, not by path:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pic1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(),
                                R.drawable.icon);
```