# Android Load Image in Web View

Tags: android, webview, pinchzoom

I am trying to use the Web view to use the pinch and zoom of an image like in a gallery.

```
String imageUrl = "file:///local/dir/image.jpg"; // http://example.com/image.jpg
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.yourwebview);
wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
wv.loadUrl(imageUrl);
```

XML

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/yourwebview"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Now if i want to reference an image elephant.jpg in the res\drawable-hdpi folder. How can i do it in the Activity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's in the resource folder, you will need to convert the resource drawable into a bitmap, then write the Bitmap out. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3036187/1269727) is how to convert to a Bitmap, and you can write it to internal storage easily enough.

If you are just looking to display a picture with zoom, etc., you may want to try something like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");
startActivity(i);
```

[This](http://androidbook.blogspot.com/2009/08/referring-to-android-resources-using.html) shows you how to build a Uri for a resource image - which you might be able to use in your webview solution.