# How to get a background image scrollable with Android's ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scroll

I have a tileable image I would like to use as the background of a `ListView`. I have already set `setCacheColorHint(android.R.color.transparent)` in order to view the background image properly, using `setBackgroundDrawable()`.

My problem is the when I scroll the `ListView`, the image stays in-place and doesn't scroll too. I'm assuming this is normal behaviour, but I would like the image to scroll with the text.

Is there any way to do that without resorting to rolling my own `ListView` or setting the background of every cell's view? I'm not using XML for this, as I would like this to be dynamic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to scroll listview background with item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457547/how-to-scroll-listview-background-with-item)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one class and extends it with ListView ::

```
public class MyCustomListView extends ListView
{
        private Bitmap background;

        public MyCustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
        {
            super(context, attrs);
            background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourImage);//yourImage means your listView Background which you want to move
        }

        @Override
        protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) 
        {
            int count = getChildCount();
            int top = count > 0 ? getChildAt(0).getTop() : 0;
            int backgroundWidth = background.getWidth();
            int backgroundHeight = background.getHeight();
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();

            for (int y = top; y < height; y += backgroundHeight)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x += backgroundWidth)
                {
                    canvas.drawBitmap(background, x, y, null);
                }
            }
            super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        }
}
```

Now in your XML File ,take one listiview like this ::
//Set other attributes as per your requirement

```
 <com.test.MyCustomListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 </com.test.MyCustomListView>
```

Comment: Worked well with an anonymous class too! I also had to set `setScrollingCacheEnabled(false)` in order to render properly while scrolling.