# Android: resolving uri from content provider, fetching player avatar (Android Game services)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-contentprovider

I'm stucked during the Game Services implementation in some of our games. I can't retrieve the user image (using Unity). I can get the Uri of the image (Uri from a content provider), but I cant use `ImageManager` because it stores the data in a `imageView`, and I want the url/path of the image to let Unity handle all the data.

My best try is setting a `ContentResolver` but I get a security error:

Permission Denial: opening provider `com.google.android.gms.games.provider.GamesContentProvider`

At this point I can't find any solution on that, in fact I'm not able to find anything related with `GamesContentProvider` at all. So I don't know where to find the right way to retrieve the data or find the permission.

Here you have part of the code:

```
public String getAvatarUrlGame(boolean highRes)
{
    String n = "";
    if (isSignedIn()) {
        Uri uri;
        if(highRes) uri = getGamesClient().getCurrentPlayer().getHiResImageUri();
        else        uri = getGamesClient().getCurrentPlayer().getIconImageUri();

        if (uri != null) 
        {
             Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
             cursor.moveToFirst();   
             n = cursor.getString(0);
             cursor.close();
         }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Any help will be apreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to access the images is via [ImageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/images/ImageManager.html). You can't use a content resolver. If you only want the images and don't want to handle ImageView's, you can use [ImageManager.loadImage(OnImageLoadedListener, Uri)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/images/ImageManager.html#loadImage%28com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager.OnImageLoadedListener,%20android.net.Uri%29), which will call your [OnImageLoadedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/images/ImageManager.OnImageLoadedListener.html) with a Drawable representing the image.

Then, to get a Unity-compatible bitmap from the Drawable, just convert it to a bitmap. For info on how to do this step, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap), particularly André's answer (the one that has the `drawableToBitmap` method).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sounds good (more if it's the only way). I will give it a try!

Comment: finally I got it. The load image function without the view parameter was  just enough to fetch the image. Just one tip for people with the same problem: you have to transform the bitmap as byte[] to send it back to Unity.