# convert image into bitmap android

Tags: android, performance

I have image..I want to convert it to bitmap & show it as bitmap.It is a default image. Now my architecture just like following way. I want to convert it to bitmap & return...

```
final int stub_id=R.drawable.tnlrocks;

photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
```

I did this. but it doesn't work. Help to overcome this problem......

```
Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.tnlrocks);

                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(largeIcon );
```

please help me to overcome this problem......

Comment: What's the point? why can't you just show the image?

Comment: will it work when you call photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);? your decoding code works fine. what is the photoToLoad.imageView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
photoToLoad.imageView.setImageDrawable(stub_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some good examples you can refer to :

[Working With Images In Android](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Images-In-Android/2/)

[convert image into bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap)

Hope this helps you.