# Change color of background drawable of a button from widgetprovider

Tags: android, android-widget, android-styles

In normal Android code in any activity, I can control the color of a background drawable with

```
Drawable d = findViewById(R.id.button_highlight).getBackground();  
PorterDuffColorFilter filter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);  
d.setColorFilter(filter);
```

I would like to know how I can utilize this from within an WidgetProvider to dynamically change the background color of the background drawable of my  elements

**From my instance of AppWidgetProvider I would like to call something like:**

```
int color2 = settings.getInt("secondary_color", R.color.main_alt);
// following won't work because a <Button> has no method "setColorFilter"
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.button_highlight,"setColorFilter",color2);
```

**The button_bg.xml drawable for my button with id R.id.highlight looks like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>

            <corners android:topRightRadius="5dp" android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/main_alt"/>
            <padding android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp"/>

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>

            <corners android:topRightRadius="5dp" android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/main"/>
            <padding android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Are there any workarounds? Am I missing something? How can I change the color of my background drawable? I was thinking of subclassing Button and implement custom methods to set the color but I first wanted to know if there are more common or easier ways..

Answer (score 2):

setColorFilter(int color, PorterDuff.Mode mode) doesn't have the @RemotableViewMethod annotation so it can't be used in RemoteViews.

My best bet would be to convert the drawable into a bitmap and then use RemoteViews.setImageBitmap():  [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setImageViewBitmap(int, android.graphics.Bitmap)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setImageViewBitmap%28int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29)
I haven't actually tested it but it's worth trying. I found that some methods don't work in remote views even if they have the @RemotableViewMethod annotation, so it might or might not work.

You'll find answers on how to convert a Drawable into a Bitmap here on SO, e.g. here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9390776/534471

Comment: But I was talking about a button, not an ImageView. Also, how could I possibly convert the drawable to a bitmap when I am in the context of an AppWidgetProvider with no 'read' on the elements..

Comment: I'm aware that you were talking about a button but buttons won't give you the functionality you are looking for IMO.
You can use an ImageButton instead and then my approach might work. And yes you can't read the drawable but you know what background the button has (you should be able to keep track of the changes you make to the drawable somehow) and so you would use the R.drawable.mydrawable approach to access it. But if you have other ideas go ahead and implement it...

Comment: Unfortunately I will have to create a hacky view on top of the ImageButton to display the text.. Thanks anyway for your answer. Widgets truly are quite limited :(

Comment: Also I see no way to keep the functionality of the statelistdrawable with a bitmap

Comment: You can draw text into your bitmap. That's probably the better solution than to have a second TextView on top of the button.
To keep the StateListDrawables functionality you would have to implement it in code.
It's all a hassle but not impossible.
I did a lot hiding and showing different views instead of trying to manipulate the views itself because - as you stated correctly - widgets are quite limited.

Comment: Hi. I think I will go with reorganizing my layout and some additional views (including ImageViews) on top of each other with transparencies, since I have to change the color quite often (think highlighting a current input field). I am not sure to have a take on bringing the complexity of handling bitmaps into my widget code, since switching them out will happen quite often (think: highlighting current button/field). Thanks for the discussion

Answer (score 2):

You should create a background from ImageView puted or Relative layout with match_parent parameters. So you could change the color and transparency dinamicaly in code. 
**My widget layout**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:id="@+id/widget_layout">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/widget_background_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/layout_bg"
        android:contentDescription="@string/background"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widget_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/appwidget_text"
            android:text="@string/widget_default_name"
            android:textColor="#fbff00"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:allowUndo="false"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="bottom|center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Create custom shape file **layout_bg.xml** in drawables:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <padding android:left="8dip" android:top="8dip" android:right="8dip" android:bottom="8dip" />
</shape>
```

Now in widget update listener you can set any color by code:

```
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widget_background_image, "setColorFilter", backColor);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widget_background_image,"setImageAlpha",Color.alpha(backColor));
} else {
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widget_background_image, setAlpha",Color.alpha(backColor));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

last night i needed to do it!
but after i read RemoteViews.java i found what i should to add setColorFilter with PorterDuff

see here from original android RemotView.java

```
       /**
   * @hide
   * Equivalent to calling a combination of {@link Drawable#setAlpha(int)},
   * {@link Drawable#setColorFilter(int, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode)},
   * and/or {@link Drawable#setLevel(int)} on the {@link Drawable} of a given
   * view.
   * <p>
   * You can omit specific calls by marking their values with null or -1.
   * 
   * @param viewId The id of the view that contains the target
   *            {@link Drawable}
   * @param targetBackground If true, apply these parameters to the
   *            {@link Drawable} returned by
   *            {@link android.view.View#getBackground()}. Otherwise, assume
   *            the target view is an {@link ImageView} and apply them to
   *            {@link ImageView#getDrawable()}.
   * @param alpha Specify an alpha value for the drawable, or -1 to leave
   *            unchanged.
   * @param colorFilter Specify a color for a
   *            {@link android.graphics.ColorFilter} for this drawable, or -1
   *            to leave unchanged.
   * @param mode Specify a PorterDuff mode for this drawable, or null to leave
   *            unchanged.
   * @param level Specify the level for the drawable, or -1 to leave
   *            unchanged.
   */
   public void setDrawableParameters(int viewId, boolean targetBackground, int alpha,
         int colorFilter, PorterDuff.Mode mode, int level) {
     addAction(new SetDrawableParameters(viewId, targetBackground, alpha,
             colorFilter, mode, level));
  }
```

then you can use it same as me for example:

```
           contentView.setDrawableParameters(R.id.right_icon, false, -1, mBiftorIconColor, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY, -1);
```

i know this is too late for answer your question but maybe many others persons will need it .

Good luck
Armin.

Comment: which API level is that? Very interesting!

Comment: i am on KitKat,4.4.2 API Level 19 here whole RemoteViews.java 
[RemoteViews.java](http://d-h.st/aWg)

Comment: I will try to verify this and mark your answer once I did that. Cheers for the heads up

Comment: Nice, but this method is hidden. So it's kinda an barrier to use it.

Answer (score 1):

id like to add something based on @bitfor's answer.

Since the method is annotated with @hide it cannot be called directly so the method has to be called via reflection:

```
int id =  R.id.button1  //(the button in widget)
RemoteViews views = ....
  int textcolor = .......
int backgroundcolor = .....
      views.setTextViewText(id, "myButtontext");
          views.setTextColor(id, textcolor);
          Class c = Class.forName("android.widget.RemoteViews");
          Method m = c.getMethod("setDrawableParameters", new Class[] {int.class, boolean.class, int.class, int.class, PorterDuff.Mode.class, int.class});
          m.invoke(views, new Object[]{id, true, -1, backgroundcolor, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.OVERLAY, -1});
```

Hope it helps :) Tested and confirmed working on 4.4 and 5.0