# Get a list of all app icons for installed launchers and display each icon on a remote view

Tags: intentfilter, android-package-managers, android-applicationinfo

I am able to use an intent filter to gather a list of all installed launchers. The trouble is pulling out an int reference to the app icon. The code below catches a NameNotFoundException error.

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
    Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    i.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
    List<ResolveInfo> lst = pm.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);


    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item);

    if(position < lst.size()) {

        try {
            ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(lst.get(position).activityInfo.name, 0);
            int iconId = ai.icon;
            rv.setInt(R.id.widget_item, "setBackgroundResource", iconId);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            //Toast.makeText(mContext, "Fail: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Error: ", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

The issue is with this line:

```
ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(lst.get(position).activityInfo.name, 0);
```

Does activityInfo.name not return the packagename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue with the following changes.

Instead of getting an int reference to the icon like this:

```
ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(lst.get(position).activityInfo.name, 0);
int iconId = ai.icon;
```

I used the following code to get the icon as a Drawable:

```
Drawable icon = lst.get(position).activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);
```

I then had to convert the icon from a Drawable to a Bitmap:

```
Bitmap iconBit = drawableToBitmap(icon);

...

public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Finally, instead of trying to change the background resource of the ImageView like this:

```
rv.setInt(R.id.widget_item, "setBackgroundResource", iconId);
```

I used setImageViewBitmap:

```
rv.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget_item, iconBit);
```

I hope this is helpful to others. I used Kabuko's answer from the following post to convert the Drawable to a Bitmap:
[How to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap)