# How to decode only the dimensions of a bitmap referenced in an xml bitmap?

Tags: android

Say I have a bitmap referenced in xml, eg 
`res\drawable\reference.xml:`

```
 <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:src="@drawable/original"
 />
```

The first thing I tried was

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts= new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.reference, opts);
```

The problem is now `opts.outWidth` and `opts.outHeight == -1`. This is because `BitmapFactory` doesn't know how to follow this alias to the original file - in fact it tries do decode the compiled `xml` file and fails.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24389043/bitmapfactory-decoderesource-returns-null-for-shape-defined-in-xml-drawable) has one answer to the problem but does not address the memory concerns:

It uses `res.getDrawable(R.drawable.reference)` to get a `BitmapDrawable`, and then get the `Bitmap` from that. This is not what I want. It is a very large image and I only want its dimensions.

Comment: If this drawable is attached to a widget then why don't you just measure that widget ?

Comment: I'am curious, if `@drawable/original` is statically compiled in your app, why are you trying to get it's dimensions dynamically?

Comment: @ArtjomKönig the images are large. I want to determine how much memory they will need before decoding them, to avoid OutOfMemory error. I have several static background images and pick one at runtime at random. You're right, I guess I could create a file listing the dimensions of each image and ship that too, but I'm asking for a better way

Comment: @ADM it is not attached to a widget, it is a background image, and the image is usually larger than the screen

Comment: If you are not doing image processing . Then you should use a Image loader to load Bitmaps to avoid outofmemory error .