# Set rotated drawable as TextView's drawableLeft

Tags: android, image

I want to rotate drawableLeft in a TextView.

I tried this code:

```
Drawable result = rotate(degree);
setCompoundDrawables(result, null, null, null);

private Drawable rotate(int degree)
{
    Bitmap iconBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)originalDrawable).getBitmap();

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(degree);
    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(iconBitmap, 0, 0, iconBitmap.getWidth(), iconBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

    return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), targetBitmap);
}
```

But it gives me a blank space on the left drawable's place.

Actually, even this simplest code gives blank space:

```
Bitmap iconBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)originalDrawable).getBitmap();
Drawable result = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), iconBitmap);
setCompoundDrawables(result, null, null, null);
```

This one works fine:

```
 setCompoundDrawables(originalDrawable, null, null, null);
```

Comment: You want to rotate a Drawable? Just use RotateDrawable class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html), if you want to set drawableLeft you should call [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)). Calling setCompoundDrawables() only works if setBounds() has been called on the Drawable, which is probably why your originalDrawable works.

So change your code to:

```
Drawable result = rotate(degree);
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(result, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just "cast" a `Drawable` to a `BitmapDrawable`

To convert a Drawable to a `Bitmap` you have to "draw" it, like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
drawable.draw(canvas);
```

See the post here:

[How to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap)

Comment: Yes, I know, I ignored it to make the example simpler. I use this code to convert a drawable if it is not a BitmapDrawable.

Comment: You should post the code that you actually use - if you have a bug that you can't find, then you might "simplify" the bug out of your code. Also, it wastes people's time to post pseudo-code unless you state that you are doing so, like what just happened...

Comment: Sorry about that, I will do so next time.