# How to Convert a Transition Drawable to Drawable or to Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable

I'm looking for a way on how can I convert a TransitionDrawable to Drawable or To bitmap to be able to save the Image.

I have been looking for a while and I tried a lot methods and no clue.

here a code what I have tried :

```
TransitionDrawable drawable = (TransitionDrawable) profil.getDrawable();
                        Drawable drawalb =  drawable.mutate();
                        final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawalb).getBitmap();
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                        byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I wantn't able to do that, but I have found another clue, I was able to get the bitmap directly before converting it to TransitionDrawable.

Answer (score 0):

A transitionDrawable is an array of drawable ([Defnition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html#TransitionDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable[]))).

so;

1.Get the drawable you want, depending on its index

2.covert it to a bitmap ([As cited here by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap) [Andre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259237/andr%C3%A9))

> ```
>  TransitionDrawable Tdrawable =(TransitionDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
>  Drawable mDrawable =  Tdrawable.getDrawable;
>  bitmap = drawableToBitmap(mDrawable);
>
> public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
>     Bitmap bitmap = null;
>
>     if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
>         BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
>         if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
>             return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
>         }
>     }
>
>     if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
>         bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
>     } else {
>         bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
>     }
>
>     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
>     drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
>     drawable.draw(canvas);
>     return bitmap;
> }
> ```