# Use drawable as a resource

Tags: android, drawable

I would like to use a drawable I loaded from a resource to use as a resource again. I went that way because I needed to set the bounds of that drawable.

```
Drawable smiley = d.Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.emoji_1f600);
smiley.SetBounds(0, 0, orig.LineHeight, orig.LineHeight);

//Can't pass smiley like this, an int is expected.
var imageSpan = new ImageSpan(_activity, smiley);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your drawable as a bitmap, as constructor ImageSpan(Context,Bitmap) exists:

[How to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap)