# Displaying drawable object on android web app which is returned by PackageManager.getAppIcon("packageid")

Tags: java, javascript, android, html

I'm trying to write an android web application that detects all installed apps on android.

```
PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
if (pm == null) {
    return "can't get pm";
}

Drawable icon = pm.getApplicationIcon(packageName);
```

I tried with java imageview and it works fine. However, the GUI is HTML code base. I tried to google it but I don't have any idea how to display other apps icon on my webview HTML. Could you please help me to solve this issues?

Thanks

Comment: 1. convert Drawable to Bitmap 2a. save Bitmap as png/jpg and pass the uri to the file 2b. or (save to png to byte array then covert) to base64 if WebView support [data scheme](http://jsfiddle.net/mn30h39u/)

Comment: hi @Selvin, I tried this but it does not work [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap)    [pre]    (Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap() [code]