# Casting from RoundedBitmapDrawable to BitmapDrawable

Tags: android, casting, imageview, bitmapdrawable, roundedbitmapdrawable

Everything worked well before starting using RoundedBitmapDrawable to round `Bitmap`'s corners.

After starting using `RoundedBitmapDrawable`, I'm getting:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: 
>   android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawable21 cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

Code:

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable());
```

Comment: Found this which works, but still would rather use the simple casting suggested in this question above. ^^
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9390776/1525654

Comment: why do you need a BitnapDrawable?

Comment: To convert from a Drawable into a Bitmap

Comment: if you need a Bitmap then the solution you found is the proper one. if you need your riunded drawable to draw something just use its draw() method

Answer (score -3):

There is not a hierarchical link between these two types except that they share the same parent. Instead, you can check the type of drawable at runtime and cast accordingly,

```
if (imageView.getDrawable() instanceof android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawable) {
    RoundedBitmapDrawable drawable = (RoundedBitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap roundedBitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
    // ...
}
```