# How to convert an Image to Mat Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, mat

I need to process Image for my Application. I get the Images for `ImageReader`.

```
reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                Image mImage = reader.acquireNextImage();

                //mImage to Mat here

                mImage.close();
            }
        },null);
```

But now, I need to convert those images in `Mat`. 
I know that I can pass by the `Bitmap` class, but i don't know how to convert an Image into `Bitmap` too.

Comment: What do you mean with `Mat`?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10600736/4317806)

Comment: Mat is a class from OpenCV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that i found a possible answer.
I give to my ImageReader a simple plane format like JPEG.

```
reader = ImageReader.newInstance(previewSize.getWidth(),previewSize.getHeight(), ImageFormat.JPEG, 2);
```

Then i do that :

```
ByteBuffer bb = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    byte[] buf = new byte[bb.remaining()];
    bb.get(buf);

    imageGrab = new Mat();
    imageGrab.put(0,0,buf);
```

Comment: variable ```buf``` is just initialized, no actual data was written into it.

Comment: How to Convert Mat to Image??

Comment: How did you initialize imageGrab?
Was it 
Mat imageGrab = new Mat(previewSize.getWidth(),previewSize.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// image to byte array
ByteBuffer bb = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
byte[] data = new byte[bb.remaining()];
bb.get(data);

// byte array to mat
Mat = Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(data), Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```