# Can't get bitmap from drawable

Tags: android, drawable

I have used the code below to get bitmap, but I am getting only half of the image has been showing.

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.ca_buyingpower);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap    this link may help you

Comment: Are you sure that you display the Bitmap in an ImageView correctly? Try to change the Scale Type of the ImageView