# how to use bitmap/drawable instead of color constants in android

Tags: java, bitmap, android-canvas, particles

Currently I am working on a project with Particle which works fine with colour constants, but I want to use drawable/bitmap instead.

```
DATA = new int[]{16777215, -2130706433, 16777215};
```

and than passing onto create bitmap with `DATA`.

```
BMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(DATA, 0, 5, 1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

How should I use drawable resource and pass it on to create bitmap?

I have already tried `context.getResources()` and also have tried with a class

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

And use `App.getContext().getResources()`, but it's not working. I am trying to create Bitmap in abstract static class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap)

Answer (score 1):

Use the bitmap factory method to decode the drawable resource like

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.your_resource);
```