# find local path to getUnlockedImageUri

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I am able to show achievement images using the [ImageManager](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/images/ImageManager) from the URI method [getUnlockedImageUri](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievement.html#getRevealedImageUri%28%29) but for some reasons, I need to find the local path to the image because I don't want to use the ImageView and I need the actual file path to the image

The URI of Google Play Games achievement looks something like this `content://com.google.android.gms.games.background/images/d2bbfba4/61` and I was hoping to be able to convert it to a `File` object like below:

```
File myFile = new File(ach.getUnlockedImageUri().getPath());
Log.i(ExConsts.TAG, "myFile.exists() = " + myFile.exists());
// returns false!
```

But that does not work! any idea why? or what else I should try? or even tell me if it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `content://` Uri is a clear sign that either

- There is no local file
- You do not have direct access to the local file

As stated in the [getRevealedImageUri() Javadoc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievement#getRevealedImageUri%28%29):

> To retrieve the Image from the Uri, use [ImageManager](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/images/ImageManager.html).

You can use [ImageLoader.loadImage(OnImageLoadedListener, Uri)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/images/ImageManager.html#loadImage(com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager.OnImageLoadedListener,%20android.net.Uri)) to get a `Drawable` which can be drawn onto a `Canvas` using [Drawable.draw(Canvas)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#draw(android.graphics.Canvas)).

You can convert a `Drawable` to a `Bitmap` using something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10600736/1676363) if you'd like.