# Android - Drawable repeat shape to create pattern

Tags: android, android-drawable, shapes

I need to create a pattern to set as a background of some `View`. I want the pattern to look something like this:

[image: pattern]

I don't want to import any image to drawable, but instead, I want to create my own shapes, layer-list and the ultimate goal is to have a pattern as a background.

Is is possible to achieve this without having to import any external image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get a pattern of repeating tiles based upon shape drawables by creating a custom `View` and overriding `onDraw()`.

Let's start by creating the tile as a layer list made of shape drawables, in this case alternating squares of black and white:

**my_background.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item >
            <shape >
                <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
                <size
                    android:height="8dp"
                    android:width="8dp"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:left="4dp" android:top="4dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp" >
            <shape >
                <solid android:color="#ff000000"/>
                <size
                    android:height="4dp"
                    android:width="4dp"
                    />

            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:bottom="4dp" android:right="4dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#ff000000"/>
                <size
                    android:height="4dp"
                    android:width="4dp"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

You need a method `drawableToBitmap()` to transform the tile into a Bitmap like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10600736/5015207).

Override `onDraw()`:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_background);
    if (d != null)
    {
        Bitmap b = drawableToBitmap(d);
        BitmapDrawable bm = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b);
        bm.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

        bm.setBounds(canvas.getClipBounds());
        bm.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Depending on the type of `View`, you may have to take additional steps.

- For a custom `View` extending some kind of `Layout`, set the `android:background` attribute to any color in order to trigger the call to `onDraw()`
- For many `View`s it may be easier to implement and at the same time better for performance to position your custom `View` below the other `View` (e.g. as two children in a `RelativeLayout`) and make the sizes match.
- If you want to extend from `ImageView` you will need to draw the foreground drawable on top of the background pattern. In this case, you can modify `onDraw()` as follows:

**onDraw() preserving foreground drawable:**

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // preserve foreground drawable if there is one:
    Drawable fd = getDrawable();

    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_background);
    if (d != null)
    {
        Bitmap b = drawableToBitmap(d);
        BitmapDrawable bm = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b);
        bm.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

        bm.setBounds(canvas.getClipBounds());
        bm.draw(canvas);
    }

    if (fd == null)
        return;

    // set bounds as needed
    fd.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
    fd.draw(canvas);
}
```

**EDIT**

As mentioned above, in some cases (e.g. `TextView`, `ProgressBar`) you may want to use a workaround:

- Make your `View` background transparent.
- Create a custom layout using the pattern as background.
- Wrap the `View` in the custom layout (set the layout width and height to `wrap_content`).

Comment: great answer! One more question. I am trying to set this custom background to a progress bar. I am not able to preserve foreground, so i can't see the progress, only the background it self. Can you give me some hint on the method onDraw() ?

Comment: I have created new question, related to next step of my question. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36765444/android-progressbar-with-custom-background-foreground

Comment: @Bugdr0id - that's one of the cases where I think it's actually easier to use some workaround. For example, you could use the background pattern with a FrameLayout or RelativeLayout (width and height matching the ProgressBar size) and then put your Progressbar (with a transparent background) as the only child of this layout.