# Android triangle design in xml

Tags: android, xml, drawable, xml-drawable

Is it possible to make such design with xml using shape if yes how can I do it
and what is more efficiant for loading and memory image as png or drawable with a lot of shapes?
[image]

Comment: you can use 9 patch image

Answer (score 2):

You can draw triangle shape using XML triangle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:pivotX="270%"
            android:pivotY="70%"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Edit: rotate shape**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can tileMode = repeat and for shape use this drawable vector and check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36764196/4797289)

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="-40%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="90">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke
                    android:width="-140dp"
                    android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                <solid android:color="@android:color/background_dark" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]