# Android Development - How to convert LayerDrawable to Drawable or Bitmap

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable, android-bitmap, layerdrawable

I'm coding a simple app which takes two images 1)Photo and 2)Filter(Image file) and then Filter will be applied on the photo. But I also want to save the Image in internal storage after the images are overlapped. As you can see in below code, in last second line I created Bitmap Object `filteredPhoto` so it can be used to save the image but it can't be referenced because of In-convertible types.

There are two ways,

**1)** Convert `LayerDrawable` Object to `Drawable` and later reference it to Bitmap Object (by casting)

**2)** Convert `LayerDrawable` directly to `Bitmap` if possible.

Can anyone explain me how to make this happen?

Note : This question may have been asked by others but none of them has replied them properly. Most of them said use `Canvas` but I can't find how `Canvas` can help me in my problem so kindly don't mark my question as Duplicate.

**Code :**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    theImageViewMID = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.theImageView_MID);

    Drawable layers[] = new Drawable[2];
    layers[0] = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.image_1546);
    layers[1] = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.new_filter);
    layers[1].setAlpha(75);

    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);

    theImageViewMID.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);

    layerDrawable.set

    Bitmap filteredPhoto = ((BitmapDrawable) LayerDrawable).getBitmap();
    //MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), filteredPhoto, "THIS IS TITLE", "THIS IS DESCRIPTION");
}
```

Comment: Your question is a duplicate(with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap?rq=1 for example), the only difference is you'll not be able to make the conversion with the current code because you're doing it in the onCreate() callback at which points the views haven't been measured and layout yet, so the drawables aren't drawn either .

Comment: In code you can see I have made Array Object of Drawable which holds two images and then a LayerDrawable Object below that which is dealing with the Array Object of Drawable. The "new_filter" image is overlapped on the "image_1546" and when I display it the picture seems to be one. Can you tell me if there is a way to save that picture?