# Xml bitmap can't be loaded

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable

I'm trying to load a simple resource from my drawable. I created a bitmap which has a drawable as a source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ball"/>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>
</shape>
```

I'm loading using this code:
`bitmapDrawable  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( context.getResources(),` R.drawable.bitmap_ball );

But they always return null. If bitmap xml exists and drawable too, what is the reason to this returns null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is in difference between Bitmaps and Drawables. Delete your "bitmap" file with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ball"/>
```

content (leave in drawable folder only file with `<shape xmlns:android...` and give them name ball.xml) then add method

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
            return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        }
    }

    if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
    } else {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10600736/6950238) answer and call it like that:

```
Bitmap bitmapDrawable  = drawableToBitmap(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ball));
```

Comment: I've seen the exact same answer. But I don't think I need to do this task. I'll test it.