# How to create Bitmap form Drawable object

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I am developing custom view for android. For that I want give a user ability to select and image using just like when using `ImageView`

In **attr.xml** I added bellow code.

```
<declare-styleable name="DiagonalCut">
    <attr name="altitude" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="background_image" format="reference"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

In custom view I get this value as a `Drawable` which was provided in xml as `app:background_image="@drawable/image"`

```
TypedArray typedArray = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(arr, R.styleable.DiagonalCut);
altitude = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.DiagonalCut_altitude,10);
sourceImage = typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.DiagonalCut_background_image);
```

I want to create a Bitmap using this `sourceImage` which is a Drawable object.

If the way I'm going wrong please provide an alternative.

Comment: whats wrong with `Drawable`? what do you need `Bitmap` for? and if you really need `Bitmap` then use `BitmapFactory#decodeResource` method

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can convert your `Drawable` to `Bitmap` like this (for resource):

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                       R.drawable.drawable_source);
```

**OR**

If you've it stored in a variable, you can use this :

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
            return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        }
    }

    if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
    } else {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

[More details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap)