# Reasons for failed decode image to bitmap

Tags: android, image, google-maps, android-bitmap

I am trying to place ground overlay to the google map. Here is my code to make bitmap of an image and place it to the map

```
BitmapDescriptor bmpD = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.colored_min);

    GroundOverlayOptions newarkMap = new GroundOverlayOptions()
            .image(bmpD)
            .position(kbtuLatLng, 12000f)//second argument for size
            .bearing(354)//rotate
            .anchor((float) 0.375,(float) 0.5);//position change
    GroundOverlay imageOverlay = mMap.addGroundOverlay(newarkMap);
```

and this code is wrong cause of this error

```
 com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.b: Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap.
                                                                           at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.m.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11517470:12)
                                                                           at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.n.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11517470:7)
                                                                           at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bj.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11517470:37)
                                                                           at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ba.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11517470:540)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.k.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11517470:99)
                                                                           at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:604)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzed.zza(Unknown Source:7)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzg.addGroundOverlay(Unknown Source:9)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addGroundOverlay(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                           at com.example.asset.kbtumap.MainActivity.onMapReady(MainActivity.java:123)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzaj.zza(Unknown Source:7)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzaq.onTransact(Unknown Source:18)
                                                                           at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:604)
                                                                           at gl.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11517470:20)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bf.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11517470:5)
                                                                           at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bc.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11517470:5)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

line pointer points to GroundOverlay imageOverlay = mMap.addGroundOverlay(newarkMap)

Can someone help to solve this problem pls!!

Comment: is `colored_min` a valid bitmap (jpg or png)?

Comment: colored_min is jpg

Comment: You can try the `BitmapFactory`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap