# OSM - Show current location with custom icon

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

Can anyone tell me how can I show my current location on OSM map with custom icon?

Comment: I am asking about OSM not google map

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With default person icon:

```java
MyLocationNewOverlay myLocationoverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(mapView);
myLocationoverlay.enableFollowLocation();
myLocationoverlay.enableMyLocation();
mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationoverlay);
```

With custom icon:

```java
MyLocationNewOverlay myLocationoverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(mapView);
myLocationoverlay.enableFollowLocation();
Drawable currentDraw = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher, null);
Bitmap currentIcon = null;
if (currentDraw != null) {
    currentIcon = ((BitmapDrawable) currentDraw).getBitmap();
}
myLocationoverlay.setPersonIcon(currentIcon);
myLocationoverlay.enableMyLocation();
mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationoverlay);
```

I am using updated OSM dependency

```
compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.6.5'
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: Where do you add currentIcon variable?

Comment: You should finally set your icon as a person icon

`myLocationoverlay.setPersonIcon( currentIcon );`

or direction arrow:

`myLocationoverlay.setDirectionArrow( personIcon, currentIcon );`

Comment: Might need this to load a drawable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10600736/4421627