# How to set drawable as bitmap in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, drawable

I'm trying to set a repeating image on top of my shape drawable but I'm having trouble with it out. I realize this question has been asked numerous times but I'm still trying to figure out the first step!

I'm new to android so I'm still learning things.

I have managed to set one little icon in the top left but that's obviously not going to do, with this code here -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


  <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_main"/>

  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_asset_4"
        android:tileMode="repeat"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="top|left"/>

</layer-list>
```

[image]

I've checked out questions on here already and they all show this

```
<bitmap android:src="@drawable/example">
```

Now when I do this the preview comes up with this -

[image]

So, I figure I'm missing a step here. The icon I want to repeat on my background is an SVG image I have created in photoshop and then added via the new vector image asset in the drawable folder.

Comment: [How to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap)

Answer (score 1):

> Vector Drawable is not allowed as the source for a bitmap drawable.

You can check the issue posted in [google's issuetracker here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117855277).

So you have to **use .png, .jpeg or .jpg file instead of vector icon** to display repeat image in your layout.