# Retrieve Small Icon as Bitmap from StatusBarNotification

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm trying to retrieve the small icon of a Notification inside the 
`NotificationListenerService`.

I've found the `notification.getSmallIcon()` function that return a `android.graphics.drawable.Icon`. How it's possible to obtain a `Bitmap` from that Icon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `loadDrawable` or `loadDrawableAsync` on the icon it will return a drawable.

> `loadDrawable` added in API level 23 `public Drawable loadDrawable`
>   `(Context context)` Returns a `Drawable` that can be used to draw the
>   image inside this Icon, constructing it if necessary. Depending on the
>   type of image, this may not be something you want to do on the UI
>   thread, so consider using loadDrawableAsync instead.

as shown below

```
Icon icon = notification.getSmallIcon(); 
Bitmap bitmap = icon.loadDrawable(context);
```

then you can convert the drawable to bitmap from the stackoverflow link below 
there are many answers how to convert drawable to Bitmap

[How to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3035692/3321991)

Comment: Hi, that's perfect! Also for API level lower than 23, how can I retrieve the image?

Comment: @FrancescoRe the solution was based on your requirements because  `getSmallIcon()` is also added on 23 API, there is a deprecated method might work `Bundle extras = getNotification().extras;
  extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON); ` 
it will retrieve an `Icon`  
I don't think there is a way to convert  it to drawable
you might rely on the icon of the package as compatibility