# How to convert ColorDrawable into Bitmap?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I need to convert solid color `Drawable` to `Bitmap`, because I need to use `Bitmap` in library. How to do that?

This is my `ColorDrawable`:

```
val blackColorDrawable = ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I convert `colorDrawable` to `bitmap`

```
try {
      val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(2, 2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

      val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
      blackColorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight())
      blackColorDrawable.draw(canvas)
      return bitmap
} catch (e: Exception) {
      e.printStackTrace()
      return null
}
```