# Is there any solution for Resource not Found Exception resource ID #0x7f070141?

Tags: android, exception, bitmap

App has crashed, executing CustomActivityOnCrash's UncaughtExceptionHandler
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070141

this is the code where error occers

```
Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable)context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_watermark_image)).getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your ic_watermark_image is missing in the drawable folder, if missing try to add it or re-import it into drawable folder, not in drawable-24 or something.

Comment: Try to follow this solution link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap

Like:
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                           R.drawable.icon_resource);