# Convert android adaptive icon to png in command line

Tags: android, android-resources, apktool, adaptive-icon

Suppose we have an adaptive icon like this:

```
<adaptive-icon
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_background" />
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

How can we convert it to png format in a bash script?

My initial solution is: write a java program ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68141541/5506167)) and use android SDK to convert to png and run the java in the bash. But is there a simpler solution? (as this requires android sdk to run)

Comment: Your problem is that while `ic_launcher_foreground` probably should be a PNG, `ic_launcher_background` might not be. The actual launcher icon itself will have a shape dictated by the device that it is running on (square, circle, squircle, etc.). IMHO, a `bash` script seems like an unlikely tool for handling those complexities. You would not necessarily need the Android SDK (nor would it help you for a command-line tool), but you would need to parse the XML, examine the foreground/background resources, and make rendering decisions based on what you find.