# how to find out program made drawable resource id (drawable object to int resource id)

Tags: android, drawable

I am making drawable resource using following reference
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/graphics/drawables#java

```
MyDrawable mydrawing = new MyDrawable(myText);
ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
image.setImageDrawable(mydrawing);
```

Above example shows how to make drawable image by program and assign to setimageDrawable().
But I need to get resource id of this drawable object to assign into Notification Bar build.setSmallIcon(xx) which requires int type resource Id.
How to get resource Id from this drawable object?

```
MyDrawable mydrawing = new MyDrawable(myText);
mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"default")
        .setContent(mRemoteViews)
        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setSmallIcon(mydrawing); // <-- Error because mydrawing is not int type
```

MyDrawable.java makes drawable with given character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert your custom drawable into a bitmap using one of the methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap). Then create an `IconCompat` object and provide that object to `setSmallIcon`:

```
MyDrawable mydrawing = new MyDrawable(myText);
Bitmap myBitmap = drawableToBitmap(mydrawing);
IconCompat smallIcon = IconCompat.createWithBitmap(myBitmap);

mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"default")
        .setContent(mRemoteViews)
        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setSmallIcon(smallIcon);
```