How do I set background of a view to a drawable in compose?
I'm trying to make my app use the phones wallpaper as the background of the main view.
I am getting the phones wallpaper like so:
val wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
val wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.drawable

So I have a Drawable with the background I want, how do I set that drawable as the background?
So far all I have found is DrawablePainter as can be found here:
https://google.github.io/accompanist/drawablepainter/
But I can't figure out how to implement it, i tried this:
Column(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .paint(painter = DrawablePainter(wallpaperDrawable))
)

implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-drawablepainter:0.35-alpha")
but I get the error Unresolved reference: DrawablePainter
Is there an easier way to set the background as a drawable?

Perhaps you want to convert drawable to bitmap? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap
